# Bayes Estimator

Tags: bayesian, estimators

Wikipedia has a section on the Bayes Estimator.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_estimator

Isn't Bayes Estimator simply the value of the parameter that minimizes the expected loss of a loss function under the posterior distribution?

What I am really trying to ask is, in the presence of a prior is there a reason to find this estimator in some other way without going through "the Bayesian update and finding the posterior first and then finding the optimal action"? What's the takeaway from this entire Wikipedia entry?

Answer (score 4):

To turn a wee bit pedantic, this derivation of the Bayes estimator is the construction of the Bayes rule when the observable is $X=x$. The definition of a Bayes rule in game theory and Bayesian decision theory is rather the procedure $\hat{\theta}:\mathcal{X}\to\Theta$ that optimises *the Bayes risk*
$$\int_\Theta\int_\mathcal{X} \text{L}(\theta,\hat{\theta}(x))\,f(x|\theta)\,\text{d}x\,\pi(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta$$Since, by Fubini,
$$\int_\mathcal{X} \int_\Theta \text{L}(\theta,\hat{\theta}(x))\,\pi(\theta|x)\,\text{d}\theta\,m(x)\,\text{d}x=\int_\Theta\int_\mathcal{X} \text{L}(\theta,\hat{\theta}(x))\,f(x|\theta)\,\text{d}x\,\pi(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta$$
this is equivalent to minimising the *posterior expected loss*
$$\int_\Theta \text{L}(\theta,\hat{\theta}(x))\,\pi(\theta|x)\,\text{d}\theta$$for almost every $x$, as noted by [Cowboy Trader](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/371801/bayes-estimator#comment698866_371904) in a comment. At least this is how it is defined in [Jim Berger's book](https://amzn.to/2CQzdlz) (and [in mine](http://amzn.to/2kxykkw)).

Comment: "Fubini always applicable in statistics' is too wide a question but for the problem above it is since the loss function is non-negative. There are situations when minimizing posterior espected loss is not equivalent to minimizing Bayes risk, namely when the latter is infinite.

Comment: So this wiki entry is actually somewhat wrong. Because according to what you write above and to my other questions, when bayes risk is infinite (for all possible estimators available?) we cannot really talk about bayes risk in terms of posterior expected loss (they are not mathematically equivalent), and this is actually the definition of generalized bayes estimator. Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes correct, a generalised Bayes estimator corresponds to an infinite Bayes risk.

Answer (score 3):

From the first line of the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_estimator):

> ... a **Bayes estimator** or a **Bayes action** is an estimator or decision rule that minimizes the posterior expected value of a loss function (i.e., the **posterior expected loss**).

So yes, the Bayes estimator minimises the expected loss under the posterior; the estimator will be determined by the prior, the likelihood, and the loss function.  It can be written directly as:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\hat{\theta}_\text{Bayes} 
&\equiv \underset{\hat{\theta}}{\text{arg min }} \int L(\theta, \hat{\theta}) dP(\theta|\mathbf{x}) \\[10pt]
&= \underset{\hat{\theta}}{\text{arg min }} \int L(\theta, \hat{\theta}) L_\mathbf{x}(\theta) \pi(\theta) d\theta.
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

where the minimisation is taken over all possible estimators $\hat{\theta}: \mathscr{X} \rightarrow \Theta$.  Usually you would find this estimator by first determining the posterior distribution, and then minimising the expected loss under this distribution.  In some cases you might obtain it more directly without an intermediate step.

Comment: In which situations would you obtain without using the Bayes rule? I mean they dedicated an entire section to this in Wikipedia, which you summarized in a paragraph. Is there something deeper here?

Comment: The second line of the equation above already uses Bayes' rule to split out the posterior into its constituent parts, so if you found the estimator by dealing with this optimisation problem, you would already have (implicit) used Bayes' rule.  My answer here is just a very terse summary of the Bayes estimator, whereas the Wikipedia article breaks it down into smaller parts and gives a lot more discussion.

Comment: One more thing. In this wikipedia entry they also refer to the above risk as Bayes Risk, but in many other resources Bayes Risk is defined as averaging over both the posterior and the data. The above is referred as posterior expected loss (in the article they used both terms for the posterior averaging only). Which one is the correct terminology?